# What measures should go into fact tables (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, ssms, data-warehouse

I am trying to develop a multi-dimensional database. I am a little confused in what measures are included in the facts table.

Data-Set - https://www.kaggle.com/johnolafenwa/us-census-data

Currently, These are my dimensions tables

```
**Person Table**
    personID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    age_group varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    race varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    relationship varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    martial_status varchar(20) NOT NULL,

**Education Table**
    educationID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    education_num INT NOT NULL,
    education varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    education_level varchar(20) NOT NULL,

**Employment Table**
    employmentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    occupation varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    workclass varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    is_Government varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    hours_per_week INT NOT NULL,

**Income Table**
    incomeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    capital_loss INT NOT NULL,
    capital_gains INT NOT NULL,
    greater_then_50K varchar(5) NOT NULL,
```

I'm very confused in what to measure. For instance, how many measures should be there? These were some I was thinking of to answer business questions:

total_capital_gains AND total_capital_loss (additive)
average_capital_gains AND average_capital_loss (semi-additive)
total_hours_per_week (additive)
average_hours_per_week (semi-additive)

Trying to understand what these measures would look like in their grain. For example, the finest grain would be per person. The next roll up would be possible per age group etc..

I understand that percentage can be a good measure, but I am not sure what ratio I should check.

Sorry if I am asking the wrong question, but I am really stuck on this concept.

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. Reading it, I feel like there is no unique answer and that you are more looking to have a discussion on the topic. For having a discussion, I think kaggle forum is the best place.

Comment: @microcosme Thanks! I will do. The question I was trying to ask is what measures would be good for a dataset like above. I'm used to seeing sale measures which is easier but this dataset is harder to get a good measure from. Are the ones I suggested valid or too simple/complex? Cheers for the response